# `download.file()` giving warning messages and not downloading when using `lapply` or `map`

Tags: r

I keep getting the same error when trying to download a few websites.

The error:

`Warning messages:
1: In download.file(x, destfile = paste0("D:/temp/", filing_info$accession_number,  :
  only first element of 'destfile' argument used`

I am trying to use the `map` or `apply` functions to take a url and download the contents and save it

Data:

URL:

```
url <- c("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746918004978/0001047469-18-004978-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746917004528/0001047469-17-004528-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746916014299/0001047469-16-014299-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746915006136/0001047469-15-006136-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746914006243/0001047469-14-006243-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746913007797/0001047469-13-007797-index.htm"
)
```

IDs:

```
IDS <- c("0001047469-18-004978", "0001047469-17-004528", "0001047469-16-014299", 
"0001047469-15-006136", "0001047469-14-006243", "0001047469-13-007797"
)
```

Code:

```
library(purrr)
Map(function(x) {
  download.file(x, destfile = paste0("D:/temp/", IDS, ".htm"), quiet = FALSE)
}, url)
```

Other attempts:

```
map( url, function(x) {
  download.file(x, destfile = paste0("D:/temp/", IDS, ".htm"), quiet = FALSE)
})

lapply( url, function(x) {
  download.file(x, destfile = paste0("D:/temp/", IDS, ".htm"), quiet = FALSE)
})

sapply( url, function(x) {
  download.file(x, destfile = paste0("D:/temp/", IDS, ".htm"), quiet = FALSE)
})
```

EDIT: Here is a better representation of my data

```
data <- structure(list(links = structure(6:1, .Label = c("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746913007797/0001047469-13-007797-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746914006243/0001047469-14-006243-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746915006136/0001047469-15-006136-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746916014299/0001047469-16-014299-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746917004528/0001047469-17-004528-index.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746918004978/0001047469-18-004978-index.htm"
), class = "factor"), IDS = structure(6:1, .Label = c("0001047469-13-007797", 
"0001047469-14-006243", "0001047469-15-006136", "0001047469-16-014299", 
"0001047469-17-004528", "0001047469-18-004978"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

The code then looks like:

```
map(data$links, function(x) {
  download.file(x, destfile = paste0("D:/temp/", data$IDS, ".htm"), quiet = FALSE)
})
```

Comment: You should be using `x` rather than `IDS` in the `destfile=` name (since you used `x` as the parameter of your function). Also the IDS don't seem to be complete URLs. you should pass a full URL to `download.file`.

Comment: Thanks, I have added a small edit with a better representation of my data. The `urls` are the `links` column. the `destfile = ` is just using a unique ID number to save the files so they do not over write each other. How can I use `x` inside the function? `x$IDS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you need to loop over both the IDs and the Links. In order to iterate both lists, use `map2`. Actually since you aren't really returning a value and are just calling it for it's side effects, then you can use `walk2` rather than `map2`.

```
walk2(data$links, data$IDS, function(link, id) {
  download.file(link, destfile = paste0("D:/temp/", id, ".htm"), quiet = FALSE)
})
```

Comment: Thanks! it works great on the larger dataset! - whats the difference between `map` and `map2`?  and then `walk` and `walk2`?

Comment: Map and walk work on one vector, map2 and walk2 work on two vectors at the same time. Map returns a value, walk does not.

Comment: Thanks! Does it go any further than `walk2` or `map2`?